# Visual Studio 2022 restarts when try to open HTML file

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using **Visual Studio 2022**
When I try to open a  `.html` file,
it shows following pop-up for some time & then the application restarts, but it didn't open the file.
[image: popup]

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: File size is `1kb`

Comment: If you can reproduce this through the VS Feedback tool, it can capture a crash dump for the team to investigate.